# Почему foreach не работает с динамическим массивом?

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("Write number of array elements");
   int size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   int[] array = new int[size];
   foreach(int x in array)
     {               
        Console.WriteLine($"Elements of array:{x}");
     }
   Console.ReadLine();
```

Выводит одни 0, но если использовать цикл:

```
Console.WriteLine("Write number of array elements");
            int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] array = new int[size];
            int i = 0;
            for(;i<array.Length;)
            {               
                Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
                i++;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Цикл уже выводит элементы массива.

Comment: Цикл уже выводит не элементы массива, а их индексы.

Comment: `Цикл уже выводит элементы массива.` - не верно, вы выводите индекс (`i`), а не элемент массива. Ваш массив пустой, вы его не заполнили, вот и выдает сплошные нули.

Comment: 1) в вашем коде нет динамического массива 2) вы в первом случае выводите элементы массива в консоль, а во втором какую то другую переменную.

Comment: @tym32167, почему он не динамический?

Comment: потому что вы не можете изменить его размер

Comment: @tym32167, но в переменную size же записывается число  кол-ва элементов - значит, я могу изменить размер

Comment: переменная `size` к уже созданному массиву никакого отношения не имеет, если считаете, что можете изменить размер массива - попробуйте это сделать. Всё, что вы сможете, это создать новый массив, а существующий изменить у вас не получится.

Answer (score 1):

и в том, и в том случае выводятся нули, т.к. массив пуст и соответственно заполнен одними нулями

```
            Console.WriteLine("Write number of array elements");
        int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] array = new int[size];

        //считываем значения
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length;i++)
            array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //выводим
        foreach(int number in array)
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        Console.ReadKey();
```